# How to catch and modify data over exception occurred during Stream usage

Tags: java, error-handling, java-8, stream, java-stream

I am currently working over CSV exports. I am fetching header from properties file with below code -

```
String[] csvHeader = exportables.get(0).getCSVHeaderMap(currentUser).keySet().stream().
map(s ->messageSource.getMessage("report."+s, null, locale)).toArray(String[]::new);
```

The above code works well. But i need to find a way to handle exception and also fetch data from another file, if it is not found in above file. I am expecting to use somewhat below code -

```
try{
    exportables.get(0).getCSVHeaderMap(currentUser).keySet().stream().
    map(s ->messageSource.getMessage("report."+s, null, locale)).toArray(String[]::new);
    }catch(NoSuchMessageException e){
    // code to work over lacking properties 
    }
```

I want to catch the 's' element in catch block (or in other good way). So that i can fetch it from another file and also add its return to current `csvHeader`.

Comment: *"But i need to find a way to handle exception"* -- What exception? Also in *which/what* scenario will you get an exception?

Comment: It was `NoSuchMessageException`. I had mentioned it below the text. Sorry if my question was unclear to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to make for each element a try catch block like:

```
 exportables.get(0).getCSVHeaderMap(currentUser).keySet().stream().
map(s -> {
            String result;//Put the class to which you map

            try{
                result = messageSource.getMessage("report."+s, null, locale);
              }catch(NoSuchMessageException e){
              // code to work over lacking properties here you have access to s
              }
              return result;
         }
   ).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Another solution will be to check for specific problems and then there is no need to catch exceptions. For example if `s` is null and then you want to get the data from another place:

```
 exportables.get(0).getCSVHeaderMap(currentUser).keySet().stream().
map(s -> {
            String result;//Put the class to which you map
            if(null == s)// Some condition that you want to check.
            {
                //get info from another place
                //result = ....
            }
            else
            {
                result = messageSource.getMessage("report."+s, null, locale);
            }
            return result;
         }
   ).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: in my case, `s` won't be coming null. Also, I am getting `missing return statement` for above code.Sorry i am new to streams.

Comment: O.K. I add return to the code. The second code you have to adapt it a little to your needs because I don't know when NoSuchMessageException is thrown. If you don't have idea then you can leave the first example